# Rating arredonda para estrelas fixas

Tags: android

Bom preciso por exemplo:

> Preencher 4 estrelas e meia

Para setar o valor faço assim:

```
ratingBar.setRating((float) restaurante.getMedia());
```

Quando vem a informação de por exemplo `4.5` ele arredonda para cima colocando assim `5 estrelas` ja quando mando por exemplo `4.2` ele arredonda para `4 estrelas` Preciso que mostre no caso de `4.1 até 4.9` meia estrela

Dentro da minha `entidade` `restaurante` tenho os metodos `GET:SET`

```
private float media;

public float getMedia() {
    return media;
}

public void setMedia(float media) {
    this.media = media;
}
```

e assim seto o retorno:

```
restaurante.setMedia(Float.valueOf(jRestaurante.getString("media")));
```

Comment: Tentou usar Float.parseFloat?

Comment: não, vou tentar aqui e te falo

Comment: @NayronMorais assim no caso ?         ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(restaurante.getMedia())));

Comment: Se for deste jeito nao funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `setRating()` recebe um `float` para poder considerar os decimais para renderizar parcialmente a estrela.

No entanto, para que funcione, além de ser necessário que o valor que recebe tenha decimais, é necessário indicar a granularidade(em como o preenchimento da estrela varia com as decimais do valor) do *rating bar*.

A granularidade é indicada usando o método [setStepSize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setRating(float)).

Se quer que ela seja de meia estrela deve usar

```
ratingBar.setStepSize(0.5);
```

Se pretende que a granularidade seja ao nível da décima use

```
ratingBar.setStepSize(0.1);
```